# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Flipper-Glog": In Podfile:

Tags: ios, react-native

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Flipper-Glog":
In Podfile:
Flipper-Glog (= 0.5.0.4)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Flipper-Glog (= 0.5.0.4)`.

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["\`pod repo update\` does not happen" error in CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030317/pod-repo-update-does-not-happen-error-in-cocoapods)

Answer (score 8):

Disable everything related to flipper in `Podfile` and then `cd ios && pod install`

```
# use_flipper!()
```

Answer (score 8):

Worked after using this command:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building from a fresh Reach Native Project, there should be no need to edit any files in the project to get it to run.

Try the solutions here:
[React native ios - error when running pod install (installing Flipper-Glog)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198929/react-native-ios-error-when-running-pod-install-installing-flipper-glog)

I encountered this problem after deleting all my iOS caches and setting some Virtual Env. Opening Xcode and simulator once then try "pod install" should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or comment this line from your ios/Podfile in react native.

```
# use_flipper!()
```

Answer (score -1):

For M1 chip Mac, run
`"arch -x86_64 pod install"`
solved it.

Comment: I shrunk this to an answer. please review the syntax (I am not sure about whether you mean the `"` to actually be part of the code). Also, please consider to add an explanation of how your code works and why it helps.